# Is it possible to use API Gateway Websockets to somehow wait for lambda function to finish executing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use API Gateway as my API interface between Frontend and Lambda functions. Since API gateway has the maximum timout for 30 seconds and lambda take much time to do the computation, can we use the API Gateway Web socket to make this possible?

I currently am creating RESTful API's on API Gateway and found out about the Web sockets on API Gateway.

Do anyone has suggestions on how to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your Lambda function is doing, it may be worthwhile to increase the Lambda `Memory` configuration. Copied from the [Lambda Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html) *emphasis mine*:

> **Memory** – The amount of memory available to the function during execution. [...] *Lambda allocates CPU power linearly in proportion to the amount of memory configured.*

Thus, by increasing the amount of Lambda memory, you also increase the Lambda CPU performance. For computational intensive operations this configuration can significantly decrease the response time, hopefully less than the API Gateway 30s timeout.

Comment: I have used the maximum allowed memory in Lambda and implemented multithreading in Python for computation. Still exceeding the 30 second limit. Any other ways?

Comment: Is it possible to pre-calculate the values and cache / store the result (e.g. using DynamoDB)? Perhaps there are some intermediate values that can be stored?